# How to become an unprivileged user with unknown password in ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to make sure that a postgresql database is created.

For this I have a playbook with a postgresql role. The login to the server via ssh uses an unprivileged user, lets name him sshUser. Whenever I want to run a command as a privileged user I use become_user: root. In the config I enabled become_ask_pass for the root user.

```
- name: Add the user 'postgres'
  user:
    name: postgres
    state: present
  become_user: root
```

```
[privilege_escalation]
become_user=root
become_ask_pass=True
```

Now I want to check for the database as user postgres. In non ansible terms I want to become root und than sudo -u postgres psql, since I have the root password but not the postgres password. If I am not root I get "sshUser is not in the sudoers file" when trying this:

```
- name: Ensure database is created
  postgresql_db: 
    name: "{{ db_name }}"
    encoding: UTF-8
    state: present
  become_user: postgres
```

Is there a way to become user as root?

EDIT: What I've tried so far:

I tried using become: yes globally as well as locally, probably any combination auf become_method: su | sudo as well as enabling pipelining and allow_world_readable_tmpfiles in the config.

The errors are either

- "wrong su password" when using any combination of become: yes and become_method: su
- "sshUser is not in the sudoers file" when using any combination of become: yes and become_method: sudu
- "peer authentication of user postgres failed" when not using become: yes at all.

The last one is a postgresql error, so I am not sure if it is a step closer to where I want to be since it seems to use the correct user. sudo -u postgres psql definetly works though, so I don't know why it should have problems authenticating if the user postgres was logged in correctly.

I am using Ansible 2.5.1, the host I want to install postgresql is a debian buster.

Comment: Ansible isn't able to perform this sort of two-step privilege escalation. You would need to grant your `sshUser` the ability to `sudo` to the `postgres` user.

Comment: Are you sure that `psql --user=postgres` (when executed by `root` on the local machine) won't just do the right thing? Looking in `pg_hba.conf` will tell who is and isn't allowed to do what

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel it will, but how can I use that to ensure a database with ansible? Because as far as I know I cannot do this in one command right?

Comment: By using the explicit [`login_user:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/postgresql_db_module.html#parameters) parameter along with your normal `become_user:` statement so that `root` executes `createdb --user=postgres` resulting in the correct outcome

Comment: sorry for the late reply: This (as well as psql --user=postgres) does not work if there is no md5 login for postgres (i think). Without adding the postgres user+password initialy i get the error "peer authentication failed".

Answer (score 1):

As larsks mentioned it is not possible to chain user changes. This is documented at: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user

> Methods cannot be chained. You cannot use sudo /bin/su - to become a user, you need to have privileges to run the command as that user in sudo or be able to su directly to it

I am still looking for a workaround, but for now i will add the sshUser to the sudoers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set new become pass inside playbook

```
  - name: set password variable
    set_fact: 
      ansible_become_pass: "{{ newPassword }}"
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html

> Passwords for enable mode
>
> If you need a password to enter enable mode, you can specify it in one
>   of two ways:
>
> providing the --ask-become-pass command line option setting the
>   ansible_become_pass connection variable

Comment: I have set the ansible_become_pass but I need to provide the root password there, not the postgres users password